# Add link in Field help Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Can I add a link/url in field help of a custom field in NetSuite.
[image: Field Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Make sure you wrap the text you set for the custom field's help display setting in html tags.

```
<html>Custom item field help with a link. <a href="https://www.example.com">Web site</a></html>
```

[image: Image showing result of sample code.]

As mentioned in the help for Setting Display Options for Custom Fields:

> In the **Help** field, enter a brief description of the kind of
>   information you want entered in the field.
>
> The help is available when the name of the field is clicked.
>
> You can enter HTML in the field. Be sure to begin your markup source
>   with `<html>` and end with `</html>`.